# How to apply CSS on mobile on specific pages only

Tags: css, shopify, liquid

**Set-up**

I have a Shopify webshop with a sticky header.

ONLY on mobile I DONT want a sticky header on product pages.

---

**Current CSS**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {    
      #shopify-section-header {
        position: inherit;
      }    
    }
```

This CSS makes header not sticky for mobile.

But applying liquid code such that,

```
{% if request.path contains '/products/' %}    
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {    
          #shopify-section-header {
            position: inherit;
          }    
        }    
{% endif %}
```

Doesn't do anything.

Neither does,

```
.template-product { 
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {    
          #shopify-section-header {
            position: inherit;
          }    
        }    
}
```

as suggested [here](https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-design/css-for-a-specific-page/m-p/689113/highlight/true#M171668).

---

**Question**

How do I make header not sticky only on product pages?

- product pages have '/products/' in the href

Comment: `@media` queries cannot be inside CSS rules, they need to be top-level.

Comment: Also, your `@media` query does not actually select mobile users: it affects **all** visitors with viewports that are 768px or narrower (including desktop and laptop users with resized browser windows) - but as-it-is it is impossible to accurately discriminate between _actual_ phone and tablet users apart from desktop and laptop users with resized windows with `@media` queries

Comment: @Dai, thanks I didn't know `@media` can't be inside. Nevertheless, switching positions of `.template-product` with `@media` doesn't fix it either. Do you know how to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

The following did it.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {    
  body.template-product.loaded #shopify-section-header {
    position: inherit;
  }    
}
```